# What is a simple way to auto populate field in a form, from a DB in Libre Base?

Tags: sql, database, libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I am creating an Acquisition Management System for a Library in LibreBase (v7.5.4), thus far, I am at the following:
A table called *BooksDB* containing the fields

1. *Accession No* (NUMERIC type) (also Primary Key)
2. *Title*(VARCHAR type)
3. Other information, etc.

Another table called *AcqSys* containing the fields

1. *Acq ID* (Primary Key)
2. *Acquisition Date*
3. *Acquired From*
4. *Order Amount*
5. Other information, etc.

Another table called *AcqEnt* containing the fields

1. *AcqUEID* (Primary Key)
2. *Accession No* (NUMERIC type)
3. *Title* (VARCHAR type)
4. *Book Cost*
5. *Acq ID*
6. Other information, etc.

The Form *frmAcqSys* is made of two tables (Main Form = *AcqSys*, and Sub Form = *AcqEnt*, relationship linked via *Acq ID*, with the view that one AcqID shall contain various AcqEntries)

Now, based on *Accession No* entered in *AcqEnt* subform, I want the *AcqEnt.Title* to auto-populated/fetch data from *BooksDB* table for the corresponding *Title* in *BooksDB* for the same *Accession No* (AcqEnt.Title to fetch BooksDB.Title based on AcqEnt.Acession No = BooksDB.Accession No).

I have been unable to change data type to SQL in a text field, so I am using a ListBox for AcqEnt.Title in subform AcqEnt, and using the following SQL:

```
SELECT "Title", "Title" FROM "tblBDB" WHERE "Accession No" = "AcqEnt.Accession No"
```

or

```
SELECT "Title", "Title" FROM "tblBDB" WHERE "Accession No" = 'AcqEnt.Accession No'
```

They are returning the following error:

```
SQL Status: S0022
Error code: -28

Column not found: AcqEnt.Accession No in statement [SELECT "Title", "Title" FROM "tblBDB" WHERE "Accession No" = "AcqEnt.Accession No"]
```

How do I do it? Is there a better/more efficient way to achieve the output?

[image: table AcqEnt][image: table BooksDB]

Comment: if you want to access data from another table you need to join them or maybe in your case make a subs query to get the access no you want

Answer (score 0):

You need to JOIN both tables, so that you can access all columns from both tables.

You need to add the table name to ambiguous column names as well

```
SELECT "tblBDB.Title", "AcqEnt.Title" 
FROM "tblBDB"  
JOIN "AcqEnt" ON "tblBDB.Accession No" = "AcqEnt.Accession No"
```

Comment: Thanks @nbk for your reply.

[this image shows relationships](https://imgur.com/a/S8bhg5W)

I entered the SQL code you gave in DropDown box for AcqEnt.Title drop-down in AcqEnt subform

It shows the following error:
````SQL Status: S0022
Error code: -28

Column not found: tblBDB.Accession No in statement [SELECT "tblBDB.Title", "AcqEnt.Title" FROM "tblBDB" JOIN "AcqEnt" ON "tblBDB.Accession No" = "AcqEnt.Accession No"]````

Comment: i would check for spaces in the name